# addJS is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, java

I don't know where is the error on that script my first error was the `appenChild` that i think i corrected using a `var head=document.getElementsByTagName.`...

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JavaScript</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addHTML() {
        document.getElementById('testHTML').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txtHTML').value;
        document.getElementById('txtHTML').value=''}
    function resetHTML() {
        document.getElementById('testHTML').innerHTML = '';}
    function addJS () {
        var newScript= document.createElement('script');
        newScript.type='text/javascript';enter code here
        newScript.text= document.getElementById('txtjs').value;
        var head document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appenChild(newScript);
```

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript. `appenChild` should be `appendChild` and `var head document` needs to be `var head = document....`

Comment: I strongly recommend (a) proper line-breaks & indentation, (b) reading through your code & fixing obvious typos (`enter code here`, `appenChild`, etc).  Then if you still have a question, please clarify what you're looking for

Comment: thanks for you speed answer @Shawn31313, i fixed the appendChild didn't know how i missed it, and remove the 'var head= document'..... because in my titurial the master didn't write it (var head=) and he got the alert message when traying the script,  and after trying one more time after the fixe another error is showing up : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at addJS and no alert inbox .

Answer (score 0):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at addJS` Presumably, `document.getElementById('txtjs')` is returning `null`. So probably your HTML doesn't contain an element with `id="txtjs"`. Or maybe you've mistyped it. Or maybe you have a script to generate it dynamically but that script doesn't run until after this one does, I don't know.

Comment: sorry to letting you gessing the mistake and not showing you the all script before but that's the  <div id="testHTML"></div>
  <div id="editCode">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>code HTML</legend>
  <textarea id="txtHTML"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="inserer le code HTML"  onclick="addHTML();" />
  <input type="button" value="supprimer le code HTML"  onclick="resetHTML();" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>code JS</legend>
  <textarea id="txtJs"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="inserer le code JavaScript"  onclick="addJS();" />
  </fieldset>
  </div>
    .....

Comment: You have `txtJs`, but not `txtjs`. It's case-sensitive.